# how can i get attributes dynamicly with given array

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

i need to search for attributes with a given array i tried this code:

```
["client_id","client_secret"] map (ident , indexOfIdent ) -> {
         HeaderName: ident,
         HeaderValue: attributes.headers.ident
   }
```

the response was:

```
[
 {
 headerName: "client_id",
 headerValue:null
 },
 {
 headerName: "client_secret",
 headerValue:null
 }
 ]
```

I understand that my code is looking for attributes with the name'ident'. but I don't know how to do a dynamic search. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `[` bracket that allows to use expressions inside

```
["client_id","client_secret"] map (ident , indexOfIdent ) -> {
    HeaderName: ident,
    HeaderValue: attributes.headers[ident]
}
```